# mle error: non-finite finite-difference value [1]

Tags: r, optimization, mle

I'm trying to fit neutral model parameter using MLE in R.
I cannot get this error, and how can I solve it?

I've got the following error:

> Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) :
> non-finite finite-difference value [1]

These are the codes that I used.

```
#Load packages
library(minpack.lm)
library(Hmisc)
library(stats4)

#Calculate the number of individuals per community
N <- mean(apply(otu_f_h, 1, sum))

#Calculate the average relative abundance of each taxa across communities
p.m <- apply(otu_f_h, 2, mean)
p.m <- p.m[p.m != 0]
p <- p.m/N

#Calculate the occurrence frequency of each taxa across communities
spp.bi <- 1*(otu_f_h>0)
freq <- apply(spp.bi, 2, mean)
freq <- freq[freq != 0]

#Combine
C <- merge(p, freq, by=0)
C <- C[order(C[,2]),]
C <- as.data.frame(C)
C.0 <- C[!(apply(C, 1, function(y) any(y == 0))),] #Removes rows with any zero (absent in either source pool or local communities)
p <- C.0[,2]
freq <- C.0[,3]
names(p) <- C.0[,1]
names(freq) <- C.0[,1]

#Calculate the limit of detection
d = 1/N

##Fit model parameter m (or Nm) using Non-linear least squares (NLS)
m.fit <- nlsLM(freq ~ pbeta(d, N*m*p, N*m*(1-p), lower.tail=FALSE), start=list(m=0.1))
m.ci <- confint(m.fit, 'm', level=0.95)

##Fit neutral model parameter m (or Nm) using Maximum likelihood estimation (MLE)
sncm.LL <- function(m, sigma){
    R = freq - pbeta(d, N*m*p, N*m*(1-p), lower.tail=FALSE)
    R = dnorm(R, 0, sigma)
    -sum(log(R))
}
m.mle <- mle(sncm.LL, start=list(m=0.1, sigma=0.1), nobs=length(p))
```

This is the sample table that I used (otu_f_h)

| SampleID | OTU01 | OTU02 | OTU03 | OTU04 | OTU05 | OTU06 | OTU07 | OTU08 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R01 | 8 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 257 |
| R02 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| R05 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 51 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| R06 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| R09 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| R10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| R39 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 28 |
| R40 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| R51 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| S01 | 24 | 0 | 4 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| S02 | 0 | 0 | 37 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| S05 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 28 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| S06 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| S09 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| S10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| S39 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| S40 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| S51 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| S52 | 0 | 0 | 46 | 79 | 0 | 0 | 35 | 0 |

```r
structure(list(SampleID = c("R01", "R02", "R05", "R06", "R09", 
"R10", "R39", "R40", "R51", "S01", "S02", "S05", "S06", "S09", 
"S10", "S39", "S40", "S51", "S52"), OTU01 = c(8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OTU02 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OTU03 = c(8, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 37, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 46), OTU04 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 79), OTU05 = c(0, 
0, 51, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OTU06 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OTU07 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35), OTU08 = c(257, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = 2:20, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: code is incomplete

Comment: Thank you for replying. What do you mean that code is incomplete...? Can you tell me which code is incomplete specifically..?

Comment: The code of which you say _These are my codes which I used_ is incomplete. If you copy it into a fresh R session, does it run? Of course it doesn't, e. g. `object 'otu_f_h' not found`.

Comment: 'otu_f_h' is the data frame which I used for analysis. It's too big to attach to here, so I cannot give you the data...sorry..

Comment: If you cannot even give a representative sample, I (and possibly everyone else, judging from the absence of answers) cannot help … sorry.

Comment: Ok, then I have added the sample data frame that I used. It is just sample data, and even I've got the same error with this data.. Thank you for your helping and plz consider my data

Comment: Even with your data frame there are still lots of unreproducible aspects to this, which makes it hard/annoying to replicate. For example: (1) the data frame you gave (which I translated to `dput()` format) has a `SampleID` column; `otu_f_h` must include only the data columns; (2) `pool` is undefined in your code; (3) you loaded the `minpack.lm` package for `nlsLM`, you didn't mention that ... Maybe you could `dput()` the values of `freq`, `p`, and `N` and include these in your question so it is easier to get the crux of the problem ... ???

Comment: @MINJI KIM - Well, what about `pool`?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the confusing data... I didn't used the pool, so I edited the codes. In case of the otu_f_h, I added the SampleID column as row names... Also, I loaded the minpack.lm package for nlsLM, of course. Sorry for the confusing data again, and plz reply me again.